# How can I print a custom phrase + a calculation using SQL/postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's the homework problem I'm trying to solve:

```
Can you have the output be 'Ron Weasley has 2 pets.'? (You need to concatenate strings).
```

I know the SQL for pulling the number of pets (2) is:

```
select count(name) from pets where owner='Ron Weasley';
```

But how do I take the number from the output of that query and print out a specific sentence? I tried using the print command with the above query but was getting an error message.

Note: I am using psql/postgres from the terminal in a Mac (not sure if that matters for syntax).

Comment: Some readings: [String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) (look for `||` operator or `concat()` function or `format()` function) and [SQL GROUP BY Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) if you want to use the `owner` field in combination with `count(*)` aggregate in the `SELECT` clause. Hint: start from `select owner, count(name) from pets group by owner;` PS: +1 for "_I am using psql/postgres from the **terminal**_" - not all developers here knows how to use the terminal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll explain the query in comments.

```
SELECT
   /*
    * Cast the type of the first element to "text" so that we
    * can be sure that we get the (text || text) or the (text || anynonarray)
    * concatenation operator (run "\doS ||" in psql to get a list).
    */
   CAST(owner AS text)
      || ' has '
      /* now we can concatenate a "bigint" without casting */
      || count(name)
      || ' pets.'
FROM pets
/*
 * The sum should be taken per owner, and we want one result row
 * per owner.  This might be a problem if two people have the same name,
 * so one usually groups by a unique identifier instead.
 */
GROUP BY owner;
```